# Copy and paste to a closed workbook

Tags: vba, excel, csv

My question is it possible to copy and paste to a closed workbook and then save that as a CSV?  The first workbook is active though I suppose copying (from a closed workbook) and pasting (to a closed workbook) would be ideal but not essential.

I'm sorry if this is a silly question I am just wondering as to save my CPU any unnecessary hardship and having to open so many excels.

The code below tends to work well enough though I am stumped as to how you would achieve pasting to a specific CSV then saving it as generally they are required to be active.

That being said you can copy from a closed workbook to an Active one though I require the opposite.

Any help is really appreciated :).

```
Option Explicit

    Sub copytoarchive()
    Dim wb1 As Excel.Workbook
    Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Excel.xlsx")
    Dim wb2 As Excel.Workbook
    Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\CSV.csv")
    wb1.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:Z10000").Copy
    wb2.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("a65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial _
    Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    wb1.Close SaveChanges:=True
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do need to open a file in order to write to it.  However, in this specific case, because a .csv file is a delimited text file, you can write to it without opening it in Excel.  I don't know if it is actually any faster, but you can try it.  Something like this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub copytoarchive()
Dim wb1 As Excel.Workbook
Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Excel.xlsx")

'//Set variables to help with delimiting the workbook contents
Dim row As Range
Dim col As Long
Dim sRowContents As String

'//Open the file for Append
Open "C:\Users\CSV.csv" For Append As #1

'//Work through each row, and create a comma delimited set of the contents
For Each row In wb1.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:Z10000").Rows
    For col = 1 To row.Columns.Count
        sRowContents = sRowContents & row.Cells(1, col).Value & ","
    Next col
    Print #1, sRowContents  '//<= This is where the delimted line gets added.
    sRowContents = ""    '//Clear the value for the next row.
Next row
Close #1

wb1.Close SaveChanges:=True
End Sub
```

Comment: Hmm sounds interesting.  You can copy from a closed workbook and paste to unopened CSV.  You can copy from an unopened excel but not paste to an unopened excel and save that.

Comment: Not sure why you think you can copy from a closed workbook and paste to an unopened file.  In all cases you need to open the file in some form; it's just that you don't necessarily need to open it into an Excel.Application.

Comment: Hmm.. well if I can save even 10% in Cpu I am a happy man hahaha.

Comment: Would you be able to provide a working example?  I'm not really sure how to go about this and there doesn't seem to be much on this topic :S.  I'll see if I can't try and add that to my existing code nonetheless.

Comment: I concede that this well above my skill level.  It'd be nice to not have to open a csv, but I am unable to do it and there's very little info on such over the internet.  Guess I'll stick with what I know.

Comment: I've edited it with some code that should theoretically work, but I haven't tested it.  I can't be sure that it is any faster, but worth trying.  There are ways to optimise - eg. using the UsedRange, or perhaps even using the windows API to paste the clipboard contents...

Comment: Thanks.  I open the new CSV and there does not seem to be any changes or pasted data

Comment: It will have appended the data to the very end - if there was an existing file, the new data will start at the very last row of the previous one.

Comment: I apologise.  It works perfectly thanks!  It does not seem to exist if there is already a file called  C:\Users\CSV.csv so I thought it wasn't working.  How do I make it so it automatically overrides the existing file?  I could delete the file each time but generally I prefer clearing contents and then updating.

Comment: This is awesome.  Yeah it creates an empty row and starts at row 2 if I've cleared the CSV.csv rather than deleted it.

Comment: I've been playing around with Used.Range as I had a 5mb file before when I used such  a large range and this does what I want.  I also make sure to delete it each time as the file does weird stuff if I don't. It also does not appear to open a CSV which is exactly what I want.  This suits my needs perfectly and saves cpu in the long run as less excels open.  Thanks again.

Comment: I've adjusted this to work with tabled data.  Though is there a way to copy visible cells only for the copy append to CSV?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this.

```
Sub CopynPasteWrkBk()
Dim InputFile As Workbook
Dim OutputFile As Workbook
Dim Inputpath As String
Dim Outputpath As String'

' Set path for Input & Output 
fileInputpath = "D:\"
Outputpath = "D:\Output\"

'## Open both workbooks first:
Set InputFile = activeworkbook
Set OutputFile = Workbooks.Open(Outputpath & "Time.xlsx")

'Now, copy what you want from InputFile:
InputFile.Sheets("Sheet2").Activate
InputFile.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B1:K100").Copy

'Now, paste to OutputFile worksheet:
OutputFile.Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
OutputFile.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").PasteSpecialOutputFile.Save

'Close InputFile & OutputFile:
InputFile.Close
OutputFile.Close

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, yo uhave to open the file.  Maybe this will do what you want...

```
Sub ImportDatafromcloseworkbook()
'Update 20150707
Dim xWb As Workbook
Dim xAddWb As Workbook
Dim xRng1 As Range
Dim xRng2 As Range
Set xWb = Application.ActiveWorkbook
xTitleId = "KutoolsforExcel"
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
    .Filters.Clear
    .Filters.Add "Excel 2007-13", "*.xlsx; *.xlsm; *.xlsa"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Show
    If .SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
        Application.Workbooks.Open .SelectedItems(1)
        Set xAddWb = Application.ActiveWorkbook
        Set xRng1 = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Select source range", Title:=xTitleId, Default:="A1", Type:=8)
        xWb.Activate
        Set xRng2 = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Select destination cell", Title:=xTitleId, Default:="A1", Type:=8)
        xRng1.Copy xRng2
        xRng2.CurrentRegion.EntireColumn.AutoFit
        xAddWb.Close False
    End If
End With
End Sub

End Sub
```